# How would I extract integers from a string and add them together in Java without the split method/arrays?

Tags: java, string, methods

Say I am given a string like (1 5 23 100 90).

How would I extract them, convert them to integers, and then add them together?

I believe Integer.parseInt(String) will convert them into integers, but what I am having trouble with is extracting them.

Here's my pseudocode:

1) Store integers.

2) Stop when there's a space.

3) Repeat steps 1-2 (so maybe a loop?)

4) Then convert them to integers because they are still seen as a string.

5) Add them all together.

Comment: Why can't you use `split`? `split` is correct. It sure is possible to do this one `char` at a time (hint) but it's silly.

Comment: Will there only be integers or do you expect strings to be present randomly in between? Either way you might want to check out what the Scanner class in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: I understand that the split method would work because it has not been taught in class yet, I am not allowed to use that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the java Scanner class. It helps you with the delimiters (in your case space and the "(" and ")" characters.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(WHATEVER_DELIMITERS_YOU_NEED);
sum = 0;
while(true) {
    sum += s.nextInt();
    if(!s.haNext())
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick... assuming you're allowed to use patterns

```
public int printSum(String str) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(str);
    int sum = 0;

    // tell the scanner to use "(", " ", or ")" as a delimeter 
    scan.useDelimiter("(\\(|\\s|\\))");

    while ( scan.hasNext() ) {
        try {
            sum += scan.nextInt();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // if input is unable to be parsed.
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a constructor for `Scanner` that takes a `String` as an argument, and lets you use a `Scanner` to read from the `String`.

You might want to start by reading past the initial `(` character.  After that, you can call `hasNextInt` and `nextInt` repeatedly, until `hasNextInt` returns false.  Add the `int` values returned by `nextInt` as you go.